# Pass all option values in form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

Within a form, I have a `select` element with `id="keywords"`. This element has `size="6"`, but no `option` elements in the HTML file. A JavaScript function that executes when the page loads populates the list as follows:

```
function setKeywords() {
    for (i = 0; i <= 5; i = i + 1) {
        var option;
        option = document.createElement("option");
        option.name = "keyword" + (i + 1).toString();
        option.value = "null";
        option.text = "";
        document.getElementById("keywords").add(option);
    }
}
```

Users then can add and remove up to six values to the list via other JavaScript functions (the code of which isn't useful for the purpose of this question), and then I wish to pass the values of these six option elements (among other inputted values in the form) to another page via `POST`. I thought that since I named these elements `keyword1`, `keyword2`, etc., that these values would then pass with the rest of the form. The other inputted values in the form are being passed successfully, but that's not happening with these keywords.

What must I change in order to pass the values of these `option` elements with the rest of the form?

EDIT 1: This is the HTML code that creates the `select` element in question.

```
<select id="keywords" size="6"></select>
```

EDIT 2: These are the JavaScript functions used to add and remove options to/from the `select` element. `keywordslist` is another `select` element in the form with keywords the user may add to the `keywords` element.

```
var keywordsArea = document.getElementById("keywords");
var keywordslist = document.getElementById("keywordslist");
function addKeyword() {
    if (keywordsArea.options[5].value === "null") {
        for (i = 0; i <= 5; i = i + 1) {
            if (keywordsArea.options[i].value === "null") {
                keywordsArea.options[i].value = keywordslist.value;
                keywordsArea.options[i].text = keywordslist.value;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
function removeKeyword() {
    if (keywordsArea.selectedIndex >= 0 && keywordsArea.selectedIndex <= 5) {
        for (i = keywordsArea.selectedIndex; i <= 5; i = i + 1) {
            if (i === 5) {
                keywordsArea.options[i].value = "null";
                keywordsArea.options[i].text = "";
            } else {
                keywordsArea.options[i].value = keywordsArea.options[i + 1].value;
                keywordsArea.options[i].text = keywordsArea.options[i + 1].text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the following solution:

I changed the `submit` element of the form to a `button` that executes `submitForm()` when clicked. `submitForm()` does the following:

```
function submitForm() {
    for (i = 0; i <= 5; i = i + 1) {
        var keyHidden;
        keyHidden = document.createElement("input");
        keyHidden.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        keyHidden.value = keywordsArea.options[i].value;
        keyHidden.name = "keywords[]";
        videoForm.appendChild(keyHidden);
    }
    videoForm.submit();
}
```

Thus, the values of the options in the `keywords` element are placed in hidden `input` elements and passed in that manner.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
<select name="name" ...
```

To:

```
<select name="name[]" ...
```

Try to do this and the values will be added to an array

From the HTML code you posted

Change:

```
<select id="keywords" size="6"></select>
```

to:

```
<select name="keywords[]" id="keywords" size="6"></select>
```

Comment: Please review your answers more carefully before posting them :-)

Comment: I'm extremely inexperienced, so I'm not sure understand.

Comment: @Martin If you could please post your HTML code for the select I will be able to help further

Comment: Does this mean that `$_POST["keywords"]` on the next page will refer to an array consisting of the option values?

Comment: @Martin yes it will be an array. you can echo it using the following code
 foreach ($_POST["keywords"] as $selectedOption)
    echo $selectedOption."\n";

Comment: I don't think you understand my problem. I'm not looking to access the value of the selected element. I'm looking to access the values of all options in this select element.

Comment: @Martin are you trying to do something like this? http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/

Comment: @Martin OK, could you add more code or files and try to explain what you want to achieve. Are you trying to create a select from array? What Happens after the user selects the values?

Comment: I've updated my original post to include the requested code. There is no array involved in the page. Since the user is adding values to `keywords`, I want to be able to access the values the user has added to `keywords`, which are represented as `option` elements.

Comment: The `$_POST["keywords"]` array will only ever contain one item with this approach, unless you create a way for multiple options to be selected. One way to do that would be with a `<select multiple..>`...checkboxes could also work.